# Where are my divs going wrong?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to float my `divs` next to each other and it looks fine in Dreamweaver but when I live view it, it messes up.

HTML

```
 <div class="parent">

    <div class="1">a</div>
    <div class="1">b</div>
    <div class="1">c</div>
        <div class="1">d</div>
            <div class="1">e</div>
                <div class="1">f</div>
                    <div class="1">g</div>


    </div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    display:inline-block;
    width:300px;
    height:50px;
}

.1 {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/

Am i missing something simple?

Comment: I think we all got that one at the same time lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have classes starting with a digit... change them to a name starting with a letter and it will start working.

In your HTML change...

```
<div class="1">
```

To...

```
<div class="a1">
```

And in your CSS change

```
.1 {
```

To...

```
.a1 {
```

[See updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/6/)

(You should also avoid doing any design work in Dreamweaver... it will create large, complex HTML. You're better off learning HTML and CSS so you have a good understanding of what the page is doing)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know you can't start a class with a number. I was scratching my head about my code because I was sure I had the correct write-up.

Comment: Not a problem @Adsy, glad I could help :-) Most web developers write their code from scratch and avoid WYSIWYG editors for the reasons I've already stated. It also highlights that Dreamweaver isn't a particular good tool if it allows you to use a digit at the start of the class name.  Good luck with the rest of your project :-)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/3/

`1` is not a valid classname, `one` or `number1` is.

Answer (score 0):

Class names should start with a letter. You use a class called `1`. That doesn't work. Change it to e.g. a letter or maybe something more descriptive. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/2/

Answer (score 0):

change the class declaration `.1{}` to `.parent > div{}` or give it other name than `1`.

class names starting with numbers are invaid.

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/7/

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

you cant´t use  "1" as a class selector

change it to another name and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Change the your CSS class name `1` to other name and execute code on your application.
Like this.

```
.colour {
    float:left;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CC0000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/15/

Answer (score 0):

Your class name can't be numeric value replace "1" with any character combination and it will start working.

```
 <div class="parent">

    <div class="my_div">a</div>
    <div class="my_div">b</div>
    <div class="my_div">c</div>
    <div class="my_div">d</div>
    <div class="my_div">e</div>
    <div class="my_div">f</div>
    <div class="my_div">g</div>

 </div>

.my_div {

        float:left; 
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:#CC0000; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change CC class name "1"  to anything like : "test"

```
.parent {
display:inline-block;
width:500px;
height:50px;
```

}

```
.test {
float:left;
width:30px;
height:30px;
background-color:#CC0000;
```

}

check in : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q2MFp/16/)